# Why is "echo $PATH" returning what it is

Tags: ruby, command-line, rvm

My path is currently showing up as:

/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin:/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/bin:/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/bin:/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/bin/

This path seems excessive for my home directory. Why is it like that and why does it have all the ruby stuff in there? I've done a little research but I haven't found anything directly relating to the ruby stuff going on in there and I'm hoping someone can explain it to me.

Comment: What do you mean, "excessive"? It includes several bin directories from where you might want to run executables.

Comment: "why does it have all the ruby stuff in there?" - RVM adds them, so that you can run executables from gems and ruby itself.

Comment: By excessive, I meant why does it repeat itself so much and why is it so much longer than most examples I've seen of echo $PATH.

Comment: I don't see any repeated entries in your `$PATH`. We cannot tell you why it is longer than other examples, because we cannot know what those "other examples" are. It is certainly much shorter than mine.

Comment: 11 directories is far from excessive my path contains 55 right now.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: there _is_ one duplicated entry, though (kinda. `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/bin` vs `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/bin/`, which should be the same here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of your `PATH`:

- RVM Ruby Executables (including Gem-installed commands)

  - `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin`
  - `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/bin`
  - `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin`
- Homebrew Executables

  - `/usr/local/bin`
- System Default Paths

  - `/usr/bin`
  - `/bin`
  - `/usr/sbin`
  - `/sbin`
- Mono Command-Line Tools

  - `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`
- RVM Command-Line Tools

  - `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/bin`
- RVM (again?)

  - `/Users/rosalynn/.rvm/bin/`

The last entry appears to be a mistake, but apart from that there's a reason for everything else to be in there.

On a plain install you'd only see the "System Default Paths" part. Everything else is added by things you've installed.